# Why are my active classes not working when i use the media screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using React on this application and I don't know why I'm having this problem. I created a navbar with some active classname in the links so when the link is active they turn to bold. It's working perfectly when I have the normal screen, but when I try to use a media screen it only works for my first link (home) and I don't know why this isn't working for the rest of the links. So here is my code:

- HTML:

  ```
  import { Link } from "gatsby"
  import Logo from "../assets/Logo.svg"
  import "../styles/navbar.css"

  const Navbar = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

    return (
      <nav className="navbar">
        <Link to="/" className="nav-brandLogo">
          <Logo />
        </Link>
        <Link to="#" className="nav-btn" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </Link>
        <div className={show ? "nav-links show-links" : "nav-links"}>
          <Link
            to="/"
            className="nav-link"
            activeClassName="active-link"
            onClick={() => setShow(false)}
          >
            Home
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/projects"
            className="nav-link"
            activeClassName="active-link"
            onClick={() => setShow(false)}
          >
            Projetos
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/team"
            className="nav-link"
            activeClassName="active-link"
            onClick={() => setShow(false)}
          >
            Nossa Equipe
          </Link>
          <div className="nav-link contact-link">
            <Link to="/projects" className="btn" onClick={() => setShow(false)}>
              Entre para a Hut!
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }

  export default Navbar
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .navbar{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #64008A;
    padding: 0px 3rem;
  }

  .nav-brandLogo{
    padding-top: 7px;
  }

  .nav-hutLogo svg{
    max-height: 70px;
    max-width: 153px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .nav-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5rem;
    right: 3rem;
    display: none;

    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
  }

  .nav-links{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .nav-link {
    font-weight: 400px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 5rem;
  }

  .contact-link{
    padding: 0;
  }

  .nav-link .btn{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #96D600;
    border-radius: 8px;

    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .active-link{
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .nav-btn .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 900px){

    .navbar{
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .nav-btn{
      display: flex;
      color: white;
    }

    .nav-links{
     display: none;
     width: 100%;
    }

    .show-links{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 25%;
      height: 14.2rem;
    }

    .nav-link{
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      padding: 1rem 0;
      border-top: 1px solid  #cbd3e1;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .contact-link{
      padding-top: 1.5rem;
    }

    .active-link{
      font-weight: bold;
    }

  }
  ```

Comment: Hi Marcus, You don't need to repeat `.active-link`rule inside the media query.

Comment: Hi Stefan. I cant understand why this is happening, but i tryed to repeat the rule just in an attempt to fix the problem.